# Google Play Console gives message that your app is incompatible with all devices

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I had an app on google play in alpha.
Today I uploaded another build and strangely google play says that your app supports 0 devices. 
I run my application on Galaxy Tab, and it works fine. But why is google play showing 0 supported devices.

Manifest Permission:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_USB"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
        tools:node="remove" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="false" />
    <permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.absoluit.christianiataxidriver.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.absoluit.christianiataxidriver.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

And App-Build file:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "application_id_here"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 232
        versionName "2.5"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
```

Comment: Have you selected any device filters on play console?

Comment: no, I have not selected any filter. and yet it still shows that 0 supported devices.

Comment: try contacting google with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. I am sharing so if could be helpful for someone else.

I am using SginalR in my application. And I added signalR library as jar file.
Inside that jar there were three native other jars which was causing the error:

```
signalr-client-sdk.jar
|
|-lib
|  |
|  |-getLibs.ps1
|  |-getLibs.sh
|  |-gson-2.2.2.jar
```

So I added following line in app->gradle file to avoid these from packaging with apk.

```
packagingOptions {
  exclude 'lib/getLibs.ps1'
  exclude 'lib/getLibs.sh'
  exclude 'lib/gson-2.2.2.jar'
}
```

Now everything is fine.
Hope it helps someone else as well.

**Solution 2:**

1. Open your play console.
2. Click your application -> Release Management -> App Releases.
3. Click manage against your concerned track i.e. for example Production
4. You will see your lates APK uploaded in the list. Click the down directed arrow on your active APK.
5. Scroll down and find list of features. your culprit lies in this list. Compare this list to the previous APK (if any). Or check if there is a feature which is set required but is not actually required.
6. When you find the feature, set it in your manifest as `required=false`
7. Update your APK and will see it in listing of play store, everything will come to normal.